# genetic algorithm matlab minimization

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I would like to use the Optimization-ToolBox of Matlab that provide a tool for the Genetic Algorithms. I have a small equation (Score= alpha*(\sum(L[i])^(1/alpha) + Beta*(\sum(R[i])^(1/Beta)) that compute a score where `L` and `R` are vectors of values that I computed before and `alpha` and `beta` are parameters that I want to optimize via the GA. The constraint is that the scores should be close to another vector of scores called `ground truth`. 
We can formalize this constraint by : " ||score - ground_truth_score||_2^{2}=0"

So for every `\sum(L[i])` and `\sum(R[i])`,  an `Alpha` and `Beta` would optimize the constraint defined before.

I'm trying to discover the GA in Matlab, however, I don't know how to formalize the constraint with the fitness function (the equation).

Comment: It sounds like you want the `score` vector to be as close to the `ground_truth_score` vector as possible -- which means that is your objective function, not a constraint. Is that right? If not, what are you trying to maximize/minimize?

Comment: hi, yes, i want the Score vector to be as close to the ground_truth!score vector. How can i integrate it in my first objective function ?

Comment: I made answer to show what i made

Answer (score 0):

After reading this example, which i think is a similar problem as mine http://fr.mathworks.com/help/gads/examples/coding-and-minimizing-a-fitness-function-using-the-genetic-algorithm.html?prodcode=GD&language=fr

I made this objective function to manage the minimization of my problem, however i'm not sure if it's the right answer:

```
function y=parametrized_fitness_fct(x,ground_truth_score)

 y=x(1)*(L^(1/x(1))) + x(2)*(R^(1/x(2))) + ground_truth_score;
      % ground_truth_score, L and R are single values
end
FitnessFunction =@(x) parametrized_fitness_fct(x,ground_truth_score);
[x,score] = ga(FitnessFunction,numberOfVariables)%numberOfVariables=2
%x will be a vector containing the searched values "alpha and beta",    
%and score is the score optimized to be close to the ground_truth_score
```